# Was Jesus subconsciously angry at God for allowing the Jewish Leaders to be so stubborn? (Mark 3:5)

Tags: isaiah, mark

> Jesus looked around at the Jewish Leaders with anger, deeply distressed at their stubborn hearts. -  Mark 3:5.

The pursuit of Christian truth is concerned about what Mark 3:5 is trying to tell us within the context of Isaiah 45:7 and Isaiah 6:9-10.

Comment: @agarza ,My concern is to focus on what Mark 3:5 is trying to tell us within the context of the Isaiah verses I mentioned. Specifically, I'm interested in what that word "anger is trying to tell us. I realize that some traditional assumptions would reject the idea that Jesus might have been subconsciously angry at God. But I believe if we open our minds to all the possibilities of what the Scripture is trying to tell us, then we will be worshiping God in  Spirit and in Truth, and we will find new insights to help us unravel this great mystery.

Comment: "what that word "anger is trying to tell us" sounds like a hermeneutics question!

Comment: @SupportiveDante 1, Seeking to interpret the bible correctly is what I'm mainly concerned about. I believe the Christianity site and the Hermeneutics site share this same objective.

Answer (score 4):

The only indication in Mark 3:5 is that Jesus was angry at the leadership for having hard hearts concerning the well being of the crippled man.  Their only interest was in trapping the Lord and accusing Him and they cared not even the slightest for the suffering of their fellow man.  This is clearly seen in that, having witnessed the miraculous healing of the man right before their very eyes, they immediately counseled together with other wicked men (Herodians) on how to destroy Jesus.

> Again he entered the synagogue, and a man was there with a withered hand. And they watched Jesus, to see whether he would heal him on the Sabbath, so that they might accuse him. And he said to the man with the withered hand, “Come here.” And he said to them, “Is it lawful on the Sabbath to do good or to do harm, to save life or to kill?” But they were silent. And he looked around at them with anger, grieved at their hardness of heart, and said to the man, “Stretch out your hand.” He stretched it out, and his hand was restored. The Pharisees went out and immediately held counsel with the Herodians against him, how to destroy him. - Mark 3:1-6

There is nothing in this passage to suggest that Jesus was angry with God.  In fact Jesus, the eternal Son come in the flesh, was well aware from the foundation of the earth that he was to come into a world of enmity and be rejected, mistreated, persecuted, scourged, and crucified:

> “The hour has come for the Son of Man to be glorified. Truly, truly, I say to you, unless a grain of wheat falls into the earth and dies, it remains alone; but if it dies, it bears much fruit. Whoever loves his life loses it, and whoever hates his life in this world will keep it for eternal life. If anyone serves me, he must follow me; and where I am, there will my servant be also. If anyone serves me, the Father will honor him. “Now is my soul troubled. And what shall I say? ‘Father, save me from this hour’? But for this purpose I have come to this hour. Father, glorify your name.” - John 12:23-28

Comment: I've come to realize in my own life that all anger is like complaining against God's Will. So, I wonder if Jesus was struggling with God's Will regarding the cross; in the times before he surrendered his will in the garden. How in humanity could anybody volunteer to be tortured to death. I couldn't. And that's what makes me weep about the  way Jesus conquered fear. Because I've seen in my own life how fear has corrupted my truth. And yet I realize the price of overcoming fear, is to be willing to accept the torture, if that's what is needed in order to be truthful in every way.

Comment: @StevieC. I believe the Son of God knew, from the foundation of the world, that He was going to come into the world and be crucified.  I believe He also knew that He would rise again and so, for the hope set before Him, He endured the cross.  The will of the Son has been surrendered to the will of the Father from all eternity (Psalm 40, Hebrews 10).  The event in the Garden is an example of the subjection of the Son but not the inception.  For Him to be angry at God would be somewhat akin to being angry at Himself.

Comment: Before Jesus surrendered to the crucifixion, Jesus said "Not my will but thy will be done." This indicates a difference between God's will and the will of Jesus' humanity. In Mathew 26:37 we find the Greek word "ademoneo" which has a usage defined as "feeling fear." Like Jesus was feeling fear before he surrendered to God's will.  In Mark 3 it says that as soon as Jesus healed the cripple, the Jewish leaders began the plot to kill Jesus. Did Jesus' fear turn into anger as he realized that the healing power was also like signing his own death warrant to the cross?